# onChange react-select multiple options

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-select

I need to detect if I tipe into a searchable `react-select`. According to the [official](https://react-select.com/home) documentation first of all I have to pass `isMulti` prop in order to select more than an option.

The actual built-in `onChange` detects changes only when I select an option, and not when I type into the box. I need it because I have to call an API if I type into that input box.

Here is My select:

```
  <Select
    options={myOptions}
    isMulti
    loadingIndicator={true}
    styles={selectStyle}
    onChange={(e) => console.log(`e`, e)}
  />
```

Actually `onChange` logs me an array with the options selected. How can I change that for example if I type "fo" then I have "fo"? Is there any option or way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we have async select option to load data from API when user type.
Below I have attached the code for you documented in their official website.
https://react-select.com/home#async

```
import { useState } from "react";
import AsyncSelect from "react-select/async";

const colourOptions = [
  { label: "Oranage", value: "orange" },
  { label: "Yellow", value: "yellow" },
  { label: "Blue", value: "blue" }
];

const SelectOption = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  const filterColors = (inputValue) => {
    return colourOptions.filter((i) =>
      i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
    );
  };

  const promiseOptions = (inputValue, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      callback(filterColors(inputValue));
    }, 1000);
  };

  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    const inputValue = newValue.replace(/\W/g, "");
    setInputValue(inputValue);
    return inputValue;
  };

  return (
    <AsyncSelect
      cacheOptions
      defaultOptions
      loadOptions={promiseOptions}
      onInputChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
};

export default SelectOption;
```

Answer (score 0):

> There is no `onKeyDown` **props** available in `react-select`'s [documentation](https://react-select.com/props).

What you can do is something like below:

```
class App extends Component {

  onKeyUp = () => {
    console.log("I see");
    // Your rest code
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div onKeyUp={this.onKeyUp} className="App">
          <Select
          options={myOptions}
          isMulti
          loadingIndicator={true}
          styles={selectStyle}
          onChange={(e) => console.log(`e`, e)}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```